# How to disable auto-play for local video in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, video, autoplay

How to disable auto-play for video when src is from my local pc?

```
<iframe width="465" height="315" src="videos/example.mp4"></iframe>
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

- `src="videos/example.mp4?autoplay=0"`
- `src="videos/example.mp4?autoplay=false"`
- `src="videos/example.mp4?autostart=0"`
- `src="videos/example.mp4?autostart=false"`

Answer (score 57):

If you are using HTML5, using the [Video](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) tag is suitable for this purpose.

You can use the Video Tag this way for no autoplay:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="videos/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

To enable auto-play,

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
    <source src="videos/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Any explanation for down voting my answer?

Comment: Why would that first part ever work? I like your video-tag suggestion though.

Comment: thank you for usefull answer, how could i display first frame of video, it looks now like play button in the middle with grey background

Comment: @Taleb: I am using Google Chrome and it shows the first frame for me with the player control hovering below the video. Which Browser are you using? Check this link once. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay

Comment: @Taleb, you can set a poster frame on the `<video>` tag

Comment: It doesn't work with URL links

Answer (score 10):

if you still need to use an iframe, add a **sandbox**

```
<iframe width="465" height="315" src="videos/example.mp4" sandbox></iframe>
```

Comment: official document too says., `sandbox` does block the autoplay of videos. But when I try the same., I could see `autoplay` tag appended to `video` tag inside iframe.

Answer (score 7):

Try This Code for disable auto play video.

Its Working . Please Vote if your are done with this

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video controls="true" class="embed-responsive-item">
      <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace the iframe for this:

```
<video class="video-fluid z-depth-1" loop controls muted>
  <source src="videos/example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you think about `video` tag ? If you don't have to use `iframe` tag you can use `video` tag instead.

```
<video width="500" height="345" src="hey.mp4"  />
```

You should not use `autoplay` attribute in your `video` tag to disable autoplay.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Video Tag this way for no autoplay:

`<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" sandbox="" width="490" height="275" src=".../n1.mp4"></iframe>`

Comment: Although you should have explained "add sandbox attribute", this is the **correct** answer to the question along with DAYdenisov's answer earlier. All the <Video> tag answers are not technically correct because they suggest you change your code completely.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all the possible solutions but nothing worked for local video bindings. I believe best solution would be to fix using jQuery if you still wants to use iframes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ownVideos = $("iframe");
    $.each(ownVideos, function (i, video) {                
        var frameContent = $(video).contents().find('body').html();
        if (frameContent) {
            $(video).contents().find('body').html(frameContent.replace("autoplay", ""));
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** It'll find all the iframes on document ready and loop through each iframe contents and replace/remove `autoplay` attribute. This solution can be use anywhere in your project. If you would like to do for specific element then use the code under `$.each` function and replace `$(video)` with your iframe element id like `$("#myIFrameId")`.

Comment: This solution did the magic for my specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
<iframe width="465" height="315" src="videos/example.mp4"></iframe>
```

by

```
<video src="videos/example.mp4" controls></video>
```

Here is an example using bootstrap 4:

```
 <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
      <video src="videos/example.mp4" controls></video>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
src="videos/example.mp4?autoplay=1"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iFrame tag, remove the autoplay form the autoplay from allow property

```
<iframe
          title=""
          class="rounded-2xl w-full"
          height="370"
          src="Demo.mp4"
          allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the source of the player as blank string on loading the page, in this way you don't have to switch to `video` tag.

```
var player = document.getElementById("video-player");
player.src = "";
```

When you want to play a video, just change its `src` attribute, for example:

```
function play(source){
   player.src = source;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aNOgO7aNslo?rel=0">
</iframe>
```

You're supposed to put the characters `?rel=0` after the YouTube video unique link and before the quotations. it worked for me

Comment: He wrote "local file." What has YouTube got to do with it?