# how to disable autoplay video in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have tried the following code:

```
<iframe controls="0" autoplay="0" class="embed-responsive-item" src="videos/first_video.mp4"></iframe>
```

I have tried many things but not getting any solution. I want to disable the autoplay on the video and don't want to use `<video>` tag so its possible without `<video>` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable auto-play for local video in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956221/how-to-disable-auto-play-for-local-video-in-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```js
function a() {
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
iframe.src = "video.mp4"
}
```

```html
<iframe src="imagename" height="200" width="300" id="iframe"></iframe>
<button onclick="a()">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

iframe does not support this by default. Why do you not want to use video tag? The only thing I can think of to make it look like an iframe without autoplay is with help of javascript.

First set the iframe src to empty or leave the src out.
Set a picture as iframe background to make it look like the video.

```
<iframe style="background-image:url(picture.png)" id="frame" controls="0" class="embed-responsive-item" src=""></iframe>
```

Then create an onclick event for that iframe and change the iframe src

```
function loadVideo() {
  var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
  frame.src = "video.mp4";
}
```

I would consider using video tag or a plugin that works on every browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to **[this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)** the syntax should go like this:

```
<iframe src="https://cross-origin.com/myvideo.html" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://cross-origin.com/myvideo.html" allow="fullscreen"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://cross-origin.com/myvideo.html" allow=""></iframe>
```

This is fairly new (at least to me) and I don't see explicit directions as to how autoplay is shut off. Try either the second or third example. This is part of the new feature policy called *iframe delegation* which will go into full effect on april 2018. I will add onto this answer if I find more concrete info.

Answer (score 0):

Set `autoplay="false"`, not `0`.

I'm not sure what `controls` does. But that may also need to be set to "false"

```html
<iframe 
    autoplay="false" 
    controls="0" <!-- or maybe "false" as well -->
    class="embed-responsive-item" 
    src="videos/first_video.mp4">
</iframe>
```