# How to disable auto play in WebView React Native?

Tags: react-native

How to disable auto play in WebView React Native. because i try WebView to play video in my App still autoplay while i add "mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}". my code below:

```
<WebView style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} source={{uri: url}} mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false} />
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: did you manage this?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/782

Answer (score 7):

You need to change the property `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}`. Then it will stop the auto play.

Comment: This doesn't work for Youtube videos on React Native 0.61.2

Answer (score 2):

Using HTML did the trick.

```
<WebView
    {...this.props}
    onError={this.onError}
    source={{
        html: `
        <video width="100%" height="100%" style="background-color:${styles.webView.backgroundColor}" controls>
            <source src="${this.props.uri}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        `,
    }}
    style={this.props.style || styles.webView}
/>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31956633/1958882

Answer (score -1):

This one worked for me in Android (haven't tested on iOS yet):

```
<View flex height={300}>
   <WebView
         source={{ uri: url }}
         style={{ flex: 1.0 }}
         mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
         allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
         javaScriptEnabled={true}
         allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
         domStorageEnabled={true}
         injectedJavaScript={`
             document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].removeAttribute("autoplay"); // this one was the key for me!
         `}
         allowFileAccess={false}
         startInLoadingState={true}
         startInLoadingState={<Loaders.spinner />}
     />
```